# If my program will work ONLY with Unicode encoded files, can I consider that if BOM is not presented, encoding is UTF-8 without BOM?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32

My question namely is "Are UTF-16 and UTF-32 encoded files considered correct if BOM is not presented?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on it and found that BOM is optional for UTF-16 and UTF-32, it`s considered good practice to ask the user about encoding if BOM is not presented.
I got information from this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223/).